# Does Juggernaut's Blade Fury remove negative buffs?

Tags: dota-2, dota

It seems to me that *Yurnero(Juggernaut)*'s **Blade Fury** makes him *magic immune* since he couldn't be *stunned* but does it removes negatives buffs placed into him?

Comment: Only some. There are some spells that are unremovable like Maledict and Battle Hunger, and there are some that just don't get removed for legacy/balance reasons. Purge and magic immune abilities are pretty complex.

Comment: "he couldn't be stunned" Yes, he can be stunned :) With ultimates like BM roar or Magnus RP :)

Comment: @MadCom Does those two ultimates you mentioned also stops his Blade Fury completely? Or it only stops the spinning animation and still deal damage?

Comment: @MegaNairda If I remember correctly it only stops him in place, no damage dealt. And his animation for spinning still goes and I believe dmg from spinning is still being dealt. All this in Dota2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all magic immunity, be it from BKB, Lifestealer's Rage, or Blade Fury, it removes debuffs that are removed by magic immunity.

However that probably doesn't help answer your question, so here is a link to the Dota 2 wiki that has a  nearly complete list of all spells and items that go through magic immunity:

http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Magic_immunity

So if you want to know if a certain debuff specifically is removed, say for example Track or Wave of Terror, then you can check that list and see if it's on there. If it's on there, as in the case of Track, then that debuff isn't removed, if it's not on there, as in the case of Wave of Terror, then it is removed.

The only notable thing that I noticed wasn't on the list was the debuff from dust of appearance, other than that it seems to have everything.

EDIT: The list is also missing Bloodseeker's rupture, because although magic immunity does stop the damage from it, and it can't be cast on a magic immune unit, the debuff is not removed.